# Why the color of text inside h1 tag is red and not blue?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="color:red;">
  <p style="color:green;">
    <p style="color:blue;">
      <h1>Code Snippet Challenge</h1>
    </p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Because your HTML is invalid. Paragraphs can't contain headings, so most browsers will try and fix your code for you which would result in the heading being moved out of the pragraph

Answer (score 2):

Because HTML rules doesn't allow to use `p` or `div` inside `p`. It is automatically closed.

[image]

Comment: It seems this is only for p tag not all block level elements  
Here Is my codepen link [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ankitt8/pen/gOPENXV)

Answer (score 0):

> Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically
> close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing `</p>` tag.

[See MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)

Therefore, your `<h1>` will never be inside these paragraphs as the `<p>` are closed before your element. You can test with your dev tools to see your browser's behavior.